# Restore a Previous Committed Version Including Excel File

Tags: git, macos, version-control, git-checkout, git-stash

I am trying to get back a version of an excel file that was in the directory. When I go to look at the previous versions in Excel which is under File >> Version History, it is grayed out, showing that the file was created today, and has no history. I've [tried](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/restore-repo-to-previous-revision) `git checkout 1f6e7be`, which also shows the file having been created today (last save of the file was yesterday). I've tried `git reset --hard 1f6e7be` which also doesn't work. I've selected the whole folder and tried to use the [Mac Time Machine](https://setapp.com/how-to/recover-an-overwritten-file) tool, but it thinks that everything is new - there is no version history.

What I did to overwrite it was the following:

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From bitbucket.org/xxx
   1f6e7be..57fa29e  master     -> origin/master
Updating 1f6e7be..57fa29e
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    FOCUS-IMAGES/.DS_Store
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 1f6e7be made changes to uploader...
git pull
Updating 1f6e7be..57fa29e
Fast-forward
 FOCUS-IMAGES/.DS_Store     | Bin 10244 -> 10244 bytes
 reader-uploader.js |  11 ++++++++++-
 2 files changed, 10 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Comment: `FOCUS-IMAGES` is a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term); Git does not store these. It contains a *file* named `.DS_Store`; Git can store *files* (in commits) and that's what `git stash` did: it made the stash commits to save the contents of the *file* `FOCUS-IMAGES/.DS_Store` (and all other committed files as well). Then it did a `git reset --hard` to check out the earlier-committed version of `FOCUS-IMAGES/.DS_Store`, which enabled your `git pull` to merge commit `57fa29e`.

Comment: You don't mention the name of the Excel file and I don't use GUIs that grey things out, but it seems likely that this file is *untracked*, meaning that Git is not storing it in *any* commit. Meanwhile, note that committing `.DS_Store` files on MacOS is rarely sensible; it probably should have been untracked all along, but at this point it's kind of late to make it untracked.